# Extending triangle file

Tags: java, inheritance, super

The classes Equilateral and IsoscelesRight extend the Triangle class. I do not know how to use the super() method. I am supposed to use it but it confuses me. What's its purpose? How can I make it work? Do I have to rename the instance variables? When I try to compile it says it does not recognize the symbol super.
Thanks for the help.

```
public class Triangle
{
// instance variables 
 private double sideA, sideB, sideC;

public Triangle(double side1, double side2, double side3)
{
// initialise instance variables
 sideA = side1;
 sideB = side2;
 sideC = side3;
}

public double getSideA()
{
 return sideA;
}
public double getSideB()
{
 return sideB;
}
public double getSideC()
{
 return sideC;
}
```

}

```
public class Equilateral extends Triangle
{
// instance variables 
private double side1, side2, side3;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class box
*/
public Equilateral(double sideA)
{
// call superclass
super(sideA);
 // initialise instance variables
 side1 = sideA;
 side2 = sideA;
 side3 = sideA;
}

}


public class IsoscelesRight extends Triangle
{
// instance variables 
private double sideA, sideB, sideC;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class box
 */
 public IsoscelesRight(double side1, double side2)
{
 // call superclass
 super(side1);
 // initialise instance variables
 sideA = side1;
 sideB = side1;
 sideC = Math.pow(sideA*2,2);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of things here:

1. As @Juned Ahsan notes, you are attempting to invoke a constructor which doesn't exist.
2. You're defining fields in the subclasses with the same names as the super class.

You could simply define them as:

```
public class Equilateral extends Triangle
{
    public Equilateral(double sideA)
    {
        super(sideA, sideA, sideA);
    }
}

public class IsoscelesRight extends Triangle
{
    public IsoscelesRight(double sideA)
    {
        super(sideA, sideA, Math.sqrt(2*sideA*sideA));
    }
}
```

and then access the side lengths via the `getSideA` etc getters.

Answer (score 1):

```
// call superclass
super(sideA);
```

is a parent constructor call but there is no constructor in your super class that takes a single double param.